# I am using Redis to replace ROS, is this weired?

Tags: python, redis, ros

I am using Redis to exchange data between two python programs. The detail way is as below.
I have two python file, `cam.py` and `process.py`. `cam.py` read images from camera and store images to Redis, `process.py` read images from Redis and process them.
**cam.py:**

```py
"""
This file read the camera and save images into Redis
"""
import cv2
import redis, struct


def imToRedis(r, a, n):
   """Store given Numpy array 'a' in Redis under key 'n'"""
   h, w = a.shape[:2]
   shape = struct.pack('>II',h,w)
   encoded = shape + a.tobytes()

   # Store encoded data in Redis
   r.set(n,encoded)


RedisPool = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
key = 0
while key != 27:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    imToRedis(RedisPool, img, 'img')
    flagProcessed = RedisPool.set('flagProcessed', 0)

    cv2.imshow('cam', img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
```

**process.py:**

```py
"""
This file read image from redis and process
"""
import cv2
import redis, struct
import numpy as np


def imFromRedis(r, n):
    """Read image from redis"""
    encoded = r.get(n)
    h, w = struct.unpack('>II', encoded[:8])
    data = np.frombuffer(encoded, dtype=np.uint8, offset=8).reshape(h, w, 3)

    return data

RedisPool = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

key = 0
while key != 27:
    flagProcessed = int(RedisPool.get('flagProcessed'))
    if not flagProcessed:
        img = imFromRedis(RedisPool, 'img')

        cv2.imshow('process', img)

        RedisPool.set('flagProcessed', 1)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
```

As far as I know, thers is a package called Robot Operating System doing the same thing. But I am now using Redis doing this.
**My questions are:**

1. Is it appropriate to use Redis this way?
2. Should I use ROS directly or is there any betters ways to do this under python?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a projiect in github:[jpolin/redisBenchmark](https://github.com/jpolin/redisBenchmark). There the author compared latency for publish/subscribe functionality in Redis, ROS and the result was that Redis is faster than ROS.
So I draw the conclusion that we can use the publish/subscribe functionality in Redis to replace ROS.